# Regular Expression that will stop at the end of the replaced text in sed

Tags: regex, unix

I'm trying to get my replacment phrase in sed to end, so that that

```
echo aardvark.CPP | sed s/'\.'/'\.cpp'/g
```

will read:

aardvark.cpp

and not:

aardvark.cppCPP

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a simple tr command like this:

```
echo aardvark.CPP | tr 'CPP' 'cpp'
```

**EDIT:**

If you really want to use sed then use:

```
echo aardvark.CPP | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*$/.cpp/g'
```

Comment: I wish I could, but the bigger project requires me to take any ".xx" suffix and replace it with the $2 in a shell script.

His recommendation was the read through the $1 using sed, replace the extension, then assign that to a new variable.

Comment: See my last edit that will make with work with `bat.aardvark.CPP` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use csh and also it's difficult to understand the shell script from comment. However if you post your csh script as a separate question, I'm sure you will get instant answers.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry that I could not help you fix your csh script. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

if you are only wanting to replace `.CPP` you can do this:

```
echo aardvark.CPP | sed s/'\.CPP'/'\.cpp'/g
```

If you want to replace anything after the `.` with `.cpp` you can do this:

```
echo aardvark.CPP | sed s/'\.*'/'\.cpp'/g
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it gives me the output:

.cppa.cppa.cppr.cppd.cppv.cppa.cppr.cppk.cppC.cppP.cppP.cpp

Comment: @JoeyDiNardo Oh I see, I forgot that the `.` was escaped. If you add another `.` before the `*` for match anything this should fix it.